# The program “postgres” is needed by pg_ctl but was not found

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I tried to install postgresql on my macbook (mojave) through homebrew:

```
brew install postgresql
```

But when I try to start postgresql manually:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

I get this message:

> The program “postgres” is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the
>   same directory as “/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/11.5/bin/pg_ctl”.
>   Check your installation.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error and managed to solve the problem by:

- uninstall Postgres
- reinstall Postgres
- manage Postgres startup using Homebrew (`brew services <stop/start/restart> postgresql`)

Not a proper casual explanation of the `postgres`/`pg_ctl` interaction but hopefully of use in getting you unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my postgres in order to solve this issue.

`brew upgrade postgresql`

Here is the question from I took the solution:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242313/postgres-server-is-not-starting